# In jQuery how to wait for specific value on variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an variable

```
var IsAjaxing;
```

I set it to true everytime a ajax is fired on the page.  And then set it to false when ajax is finished;

I am building a SafeAjaxing event so work would only be done when the page is not ajaxing:

```
    // safe-ajaxing: Triggers when no ajax is running
    $($fieldRenderPageDOM).on("safe-ajaxing", '.field-render', function(e, work) {
        $.when({ IsAjaxing: false }).done(work);
    });
```

This doesn't seem to wait, work is always called immediately.

It would be called like this:

```
$fieldDOM.trigger("safe-ajaxing", function () {
    $fieldDOM.trigger("do-work");
    $fieldDOM.trigger("do-some-more-work);
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In javascript, how to trigger event when a variable's value is changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10638769/in-javascript-how-to-trigger-event-when-a-variables-value-is-changed)

Comment: Don't wait for values to appear in variables. Instead, just wait for the data directly.

Comment: Can't.  Design is event driven, don't have access to the direct Ajax call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use promises for this purpose:

```
var IsAjaxing = function(){
    var defer = $.Deferred().resolve();

    return {
        On: function(){
            defer = $.Deferred();
        },
        Off: function(){
            defer.resolve();
        },
        Promise: function() {
            return defer.promise();
        },
        IsOn: function() {
            return defer.state() == "pending";
        },
        IsOff: function() {
            return defer.state() != "pending";
        }
    };
}();
```

And then your event will be:

```
// safe-ajaxing: Triggers when no ajax is running
$($fieldRenderPageDOM).on("safe-ajaxing", '.field-render', function(e, work) {
    $.when(IsAjaxing.Promise()).done(work);
});
```

Each time when you start ajax request run:

```
IsAjaxing.On();
```

Each time when you finish ajax run:

```
IsAjaxing.Off();
```

To check the current state of IsAjaxing, call the IsOn and IsOff function.

Comment: How do I tell what state IsAjaxing is at?  Specifically how do I tell if it's ajaxing or not?

Answer (score 0):

This might not be the best way, but it works.

*You really should optimize the code i've written, but this is to get you started.*

```
var isAjaxing = false;

var check = function(){
  if(isAjaxing){
    // do something
    alert();

    // freeze the checking
    // manual restart is required
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}

var interval = setInterval(check, 10);

// to demonstrate the variable change
setInterval(function(){
  isAjaxing = true;
}, 3000);
```

This scripts checks if the variable is changed every 10 miliseconds.

**Note**: The clearInterval() function is used to stop checking.

Answer (score 0):

> I am building a SafeAjaxing event so work would only be done when the page is not ajaxing.

Don't build this yourself. Just use the builtin [ajax events of jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/), namely

- `ajaxStart` "*This event is triggered if an Ajax request is started and no other Ajax requests are currently running.*"
- `ajaxStop` "*This global event is triggered if there are no more Ajax requests being processed.*"